# Converting a SQL Server 2008 R2 database to PostGIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, postgis, postgresql-9.2

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 R2 which needs to be converted into a PostGIS one.

I have PostGres 9.2 installed with the PostGIS extension. What should be my next step to convert my existing SQL Server 2008 R2 database into a PostGIS equivalent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off you can't "convert" a database from SQL Server to Postgres. Hopefully, you just mean you want to make similarly structured copies of the tables in a newly created Postgres database.  If that's the case, you can use SSMS to create a temporary SSIS package that will copy the data over.  You'll need to install a Postgres OLEDB provider like [this one](http://pgoledb.com/) before you can do that however.